# KashFlow Vs Xero?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am not sure whether this is an appropriate question to ask in this board, but anyone with experience of integrating KashFlow or Xero with a zend-php application could help me. We are on the dilemma of selecting our invoicing system for our SaaS. I was going through all the reviews and trying out myself all the options in both the systems. It seems like Xero has a clean interface and gives you what you need at the right time. Apart from the user interface I am really concerned about the Integration side of things.

Xero gives oAuth integrating and KashFlow gives Web services. Our plan is to automate the invoicing process(rolling monthly invoicing) and payment processing with the Accounting software. Our existing system is build in php and zend framework. Could anyone please suggest me with some quick strong points which is really convincing to help us choose one of them.

Sorry for not tagging kashflow and xero as i do not have enough reputation.

Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have a sheet that compares Xero & Kashflow (I havent worked with Kashflow) but this PDF provides a comparison between Xero & Sassu http://help.xero.com/help/resources/XerovsSaasuSumm.pdf << Online software is updated so frequently that both products have moved on since this link was first posted and now no longer exists. 
To think about how Xero compares to another product you're using or considering, ask yourself these questions: http://www.xero.com/compare/ (OG from Xero)

Comment: That Was really helpful thank you very much... I could pick up the Xero points and compare with kashflow.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to further confuse things but have you looked at Saasu also? Possibly more powerful in terms of what you can store with their tags and activity system plus they do automated sales within the application itself.

Comment: Thank you I will definetely look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the PHP wrapper for the KashFlow API? http://accountingapi.com/examplecode.asp

The KashFlow API is very comprehensive, but if there are any missing functions that you need then email support@kashflow.com and we'll see if we can add them - we usually can, and pretty quickly too.

Answer (score 1):

KashFlow have [recently announced](http://www.kashflow.com/blog/changing-the-game/) that they are going to revamp their api and add oAuth and REST support.